# How to implement multiple traits for a struct without repeating methods?

Tags: rust, traits

The code below works just fine, but I'm repeating myself a lot
and I don't think this is really Rustic. For example I'm implementing two traits for `Square` and this doesn’t feel right! Also the function `coordinate()` is repeated in the trait and in the implementation.

Is there a way to implement this code without repeating myself so often? Is it possible to implement the two traits like:

```
impl BasicInfo && Sides for Square {
    ....
}
```

the above code does not work, it is just an idea. When a function can be applied to multiple structs, is it possible to define it just once in the trait `BasicInfo` and access it.

```
fn main() {
    let x_1: f64 = 2.5;
    let y_1: f64 = 5.2;
    let radius_1: f64 = 5.5;
    let width_01 = 10.54;

    let circle_01 = Circle { x: x_1, y: y_1, radius: radius_1 };
    let square_01 = Square { x: x_1, y: y_1, width: width_01, sides: 4 };

    println!("circle_01 has an area of {:.3}.", 
        circle_01.area().round());
    println!("{:?}", circle_01);
    println!("The coordinate of circle_01 is {:?}.\n", circle_01.coordinate());
    println!("coordinate of square_01: {:?} has an area of: {} m2 and also has {} sides.", 
        square_01.coordinate(), 
        (square_01.area() * 100.0).round() / 100.0,
        square_01.has_sides() );
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

struct Square {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    width: f64,
    sides: i32,
}

trait BasicInfo {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
    // coordinate() is declared here, but not defined. Is it possible to define it here and still be able to access it when I want it.
    fn coordinate(&self) -> (f64, f64);
}

trait Sides {
    fn has_sides(&self) -> i32;
}

impl BasicInfo for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
    // coordinate() gets defined again, and looks like repeating code
    fn coordinate(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        (self.x, self.y)
    }
}

impl BasicInfo for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.width.powf(2.0)
    }
    // coordinate() gets defined again, and looks like repeating code
    fn coordinate(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        (self.x, self.y)
    }
}

impl Sides for Square {
    fn has_sides(&self) -> i32 {
        self.sides
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two questions in one here: (1) implementing two traits at once and (2) implementing a trait on multiple structs once. The title only matches (1), so I would recommend opening a new dedicated for (2). SO is not a forum, and the format just is not adapted to multiple unrelated questions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for your comments. I will open a new one for the second question.

Answer (score 10):

for your second question (avoid repeating the identical implementation of `coordinate`) I wanted to show you the macro-based solution.

Funnily enough, it leaves you with 3 traits instead of 2, so it goes in the exact opposite direction of your first question. I guess you can't have everything! :)

```
// factoring out the Coordinates trait from BasicInfo
trait Coordinates {
    fn coordinate(&self) -> (f64, f64);
}

// but we can require implementors of BasicInfo to also impl Coordinates
trait BasicInfo: Coordinates {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

// helper macro to avoid repetition of "basic" impl Coordinates
macro_rules! impl_Coordinates { 
    ($T:ident) => {
        impl Coordinates for $T {
            fn coordinate(&self) -> (f64, f64) { (self.x, self.y) }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Square {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    width: f64,
    sides: i32,
}

// the macro here will expand to identical implementations
// for Circle and Square. There are also more clever (but a bit
// harder to understand) ways to write the macro, so you can
// just do impl_Coordinates!(Circle, Square, Triangle, OtherShape)
// instead of repeating impl_Coordinates!
impl_Coordinates!(Circle);
impl_Coordinates!(Square);


trait Sides {
    fn has_sides(&self) -> i32;
}

impl BasicInfo for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}

impl BasicInfo for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.width.powf(2.0)
    }
}

impl Sides for Square {
    fn has_sides(&self) -> i32 {
        self.sides
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to macro, this helps with not repeating the same code.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: at the time of writing, there are two questions bundled in one, and the latter does not match the title. So going by the title...*

> Is it possible to implement multiple traits at once?
>
> ```
> impl BasicInfo && Sides for Square {
>     ....
> }
> ```

**No.**

The overhead of implementing them separately is relatively low, and for more complex situations, when constraints are necessary, it might not be possible as you would want different types of constraints for each trait.

That being said, you could potentially open an RFC suggesting this be implemented, and then let the community/developers decide whether they find it worth implementing or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I haven't used traits with conditions and didn't really thought about it. Now I'm carious about it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with implementing multiple traits for one type; it's very common in fact.

I also don't understand what you mean by repeating `coordinate` in the trait and the impl. The function is declared in the trait and implemented in the impl, just like every other trait function. Did you mean that the function's implementation is identical in the Square and Circle impls? Macros would help you there, although there may be a better way.

Comment: Sebastian, with coordinate I mean the fn coordinate(){ ... } which is defined in both impl's and in trait.

Comment: @user3419211 So the problem is defining it in both impls? It's not defined in the trait.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes the problem is that it's defined in both impl's and when I remove these two and only define it in trait BasicInfo then I can't access it